# msbuild task conditional operators in parameter value

Tags: msbuild, msbuild-task

Is there any way how to use conditional variables as parameters when calling MSBuild tasks?

for example, if we have text being string argument in MySampleTask msbuild task:

```
<MySampleTask text="if a not empty ? a : b" />
```

How to pass text string variable if we may have 2 local string variables a and b? How to achieve behavior in above code?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of such operator, but what you want is equivalent to

```
<MySampleTask text="$(a)" Condition="'$(a)' != ''" />
<MySampleTask text="$(b)" Condition="'$(a)' == ''" />
```

Or, same principle but applied to a property first; probably the most 'standard' way:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <a Condition="'$(a)' == ''">$(b)</a>
</PropertyGroup>

<MySampleTask text="$(a)" />
```